# Internet Explorer 11: Print functionality creates blank pages

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

1. Data within Page renders from the start leaving extra blank pages at the end.
2. When data more than a page creates blank page in first page and extra blank pages at the end.

   ```
   exportElement.setAttribute('id', 'demo-table');
   tableElement.appendChild(exportElement);
   exportElement.innerHTML = tableElement.outerHTML;
   window.print();
   ```

Comment: Just uninstall IE :D (joking)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you providing. Is there any error in console? Could you please also provide the related html code so that we can have a test with your situation? You could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to provide a minimal, reproducible sample.